# Making base maps for weather limited to exact space and output dimension in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap, weather

[image: Here is what I'm trying to do]

I need to make some pretty basemaps and wish to use QGIS.  The program which will use the basemaps is GrADS, which doesn't read any navigated imagery like geoTIFF or kml.  However it produces KML files.  So I can specify the exact domain for QGIS to render.

The rectangle represents the area I wish to output at 1920x1080 pixels.

I know how to make the maps I want, but how do I limit them to this exact space and output dimension?

Comment: Try using the print composer, with map scale specified a formula based on the domain of the kml.

Comment: I'm not sure how to move only my specified domain to print composer.  It always comes with more area.

Comment: The rectangle is a shapefile or other format vector layer? If yes then you could create a new 16:9 page in map composer, adjust the map extent to fit the rectangle. Then hide the rectange in QGIS layers panel, refresh the map composer and export the map - it will have the right extent.

Comment: Thanks all.  I have used a combination of your advice.  [Here's a sample].(http://45.79.86.175/output/nam/sfc/nam-slp.mp4).  The weather data comes from GrADS.  All the visible mapping accoutrements are done in QGIS.  The movie was assembled with ffmpeg.

Should i/Could I do it all in QGIS?  I don't know, but if any of you have suggestions I'm all ears.  The underlying data comes from [here](nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods), but I'm sure it's available on THREDDS and other standard servers.